# jQuery .load doesn't work in Safari after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari, load

I need to reload a div with jQuery after AJAX login. The top bar that should show different links for logged in and logged out users.

I'm using this piece of code for reloading:

```
$("#navigation").load(location.href + " #header");
```

which reloads the `#navigation` into `#header` div. This method works well with Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

- Could it depends by the fact I'm working on localhost?

AJAX is working fine because if I refresh the whole page I'm logged.